# C++ Vulkan swapchain image_index vs current_frame

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am new to vulkan and following the [vulkan-tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/). In the chapter about swapchain and multiple frames in flight ([frames_in_flight](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Frames_in_flight)) there is something I dont understand.

The variable `imageIndex` gets set by the function `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`

```
uint32_t imageIndex;
vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapChain, UINT64_MAX, imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame], VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);
```

and the variable `currentFrame` gets incremented each frame

```
currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
```

The `imageIndex` variable just gets used for the `pImageIndices` field of the `VkPresentInfoKHR` struct and for the indexing into the `std::vector<VkFramebuffer>`.

All other vectors e.g. the `VkFence` or `VkCommandBuffer` are indexed with the `currentFrame` variable.

What exactly is the defferece between `imageIndex` and `currentFrame` and why do I need to keep track of woth?

Comment: They only use 2 command buffers, but they use `minImageCount+1` swapchain images. [`minImageCount` is required to be at least 1, but can be greater](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR.html#_description), thus the number of swapchain images and command buffers may differ.

Comment: @vandench Are there any advantages for using just 2 command buffers instead of one for each swapchain image? And how would that look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is:

`vkAcquireNextImageKHR::imageIndex` is "random". It can return any number in any order.

The `currentFrame` changes strictly in round-robin fashion. Additionally the max-count may differ from swapchain image count.

You would use `vkAcquireNextImageKHR::imageIndex` for things tied to a specific swapchain image. And you would use `currentFrame` for things tied to the sequence of frames (e.g. odd frames vs even frames).

Comment: What is the difference between a swapchain image and a fraim? Arent they tied together?

Comment: @Symlink Swapchain Image is the memory backing handoffs to the operating system. Frame is a single picture in an animated sequence. Swapchain Images are acquired in an order as the OS feels like it; you get random index from the acquire op. Frames always come in the exact order (or the animation would be broken). It is the sequence in which you present Images. The first picture you present is frame 1, the second you present is frame 2 and so on.